# Inserting data Dynamically into Excel using Java

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I am new in Java and i have problem on inserting dynamic data into my Excel file. Here is the follow code. If i delete my excel file and re-run my program. it will then create a new file and also insert the following data.(hello,goodbye,true,date).During the first run, the program still can insert the following data, but when i perform the next run, the data cannot be store to the next line. This is the following code to check for file exist. I hope i can get someone to help me as i am struggling this code for a few days.

```
    if (file.exists()) {
                        try{
                            fout = new FileOutputStream(fileName, true);
                            fin = new FileInputStream(fileName);
                            lPOIfs = new POIFSFileSystem(fin);
                            workbook = new HSSFWorkbook(lPOIfs);
                            worksheet = workbook.getSheet("POI Worksheet");
                            for (int i=0; i<workbook.getNumberOfSheets(); i++) {
                                System.out.println( workbook.getSheetName(i) );                                    
                            }
                            HSSFSheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);
                            last = sheet.getLastRowNum();
                        }catch (IOException e) {  
                            e.printStackTrace();  
                        }catch (NullPointerException e){
                            e.printStackTrace(); 
                        }
                    } else {
                        //create new file
                        try{
                        fout = new FileOutputStream(file);                            
                        }catch (IOException e) {  
                            e.printStackTrace();  
                        }
                        workbook = new HSSFWorkbook();                       
                        worksheet = workbook.createSheet("POI Worksheet");  
                    }
```

This is the code to check for the last number in line:

```
    if(last != 0){
          last = worksheet.getLastRowNum()+1;
    }else{
          last = worksheet.getLastRowNum();
    }
```

This is the full code of the write function:

```
    public void writeExcel(){
    String fileName = "C:\\Users\\blslyeoh\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\JavaApplication1\\poi-test.xls";       
    try {
                    int last=0;
                    File file = new File(fileName);
                    FileInputStream fin = null;  
                    HSSFWorkbook workbook = null;  
                    HSSFSheet worksheet = null;  
                    FileOutputStream fout = null;
                    POIFSFileSystem lPOIfs = null;
                    if (file.exists()) {
                        try{
                            fout = new FileOutputStream(fileName, true);
                            fin = new FileInputStream(fileName);
                            lPOIfs = new POIFSFileSystem(fin);
                            workbook = new HSSFWorkbook(lPOIfs);
                            worksheet = workbook.getSheet("POI Worksheet");
                            for (int i=0; i<workbook.getNumberOfSheets(); i++) {
                                System.out.println( workbook.getSheetName(i) );                                    
                            }
                            HSSFSheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);
                            last = sheet.getLastRowNum();
                        }catch (IOException e) {  
                            e.printStackTrace();  
                        }catch (NullPointerException e){
                            e.printStackTrace(); 
                        }
                    } else {
                        //create new file
                        try{
                        fout = new FileOutputStream(file);                            
                        }catch (IOException e) {  
                            e.printStackTrace();  
                        }
                        workbook = new HSSFWorkbook();                       
                        worksheet = workbook.createSheet("POI Worksheet");  
                    }
        // index from 0,0... cell A1 is cell(0,0)
                    if(last != 0){
                        last = worksheet.getLastRowNum()+1;
                    }else{
                        last = worksheet.getLastRowNum();
                    }
                    HSSFRow row = worksheet.createRow(last);                        
        HSSFCell cellA1 = row.createCell((short)0);
        cellA1.setCellValue("hello");   
        HSSFCellStyle cellStyle = workbook.createCellStyle();
        //cellStyle.setFillForegroundColor(HSSFColor.GOLD.index);
        //cellStyle.setFillPattern(HSSFCellStyle.SOLID_FOREGROUND);
        //cellA1.setCellStyle(cellStyle);
        HSSFCell cellB1 = row.createCell((short) 1);
        cellB1.setCellValue("goodbye");
        //cellStyle = workbook.createCellStyle();
        //cellStyle.setFillForegroundColor(HSSFColor.LIGHT_CORNFLOWER_BLUE.index);
        //cellStyle.setFillPattern(HSSFCellStyle.SOLID_FOREGROUND);
        //cellB1.setCellStyle(cellStyle);
        HSSFCell cellC1 = row.createCell((short) 2);
        cellC1.setCellValue(true);

        HSSFCell cellD1 = row.createCell((short) 3);
        cellD1.setCellValue(new Date());
        cellStyle = workbook.createCellStyle();
        cellStyle.setDataFormat(HSSFDataFormat
                .getBuiltinFormat("m/d/yy h:mm"));
        cellD1.setCellStyle(cellStyle);
        workbook.write(fout);
        fout.flush();

        fout.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: Are you getting any stacktraces? Any errors thrown? It would be helpful to post those.

Comment: I got it, thanks for the help for this URL http://www.codepool.biz/excel/how-to-read-and-write-excel-files-in-java.html hope this helps you all. By the way, fout = new FileOutputStream(fileName, true); should change to fout = new FileOutputStream(fileName);

Comment: btw, thanks @jcd for the concern

Comment: Can you please edit your code as working code? I need this code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Read the excel file first!
2. If you get worksheet successfully through
   ***worksheet = workbook.getSheet("POI Worksheet");***
   then close the file input stream.
3. If you can't get worksheet then create one through
   ***workbook = new HSSFWorkbook();***
   ***worksheet = workbook.createSheet("POI Worksheet");***
4. you've got wooksheet which is existing or new one.
   append rows and write it to a file and close the file output stream through
   ***fout = new FileOutputStream(file);***
   ***workbook.write(fout);***
   ***fout.close();***

I hope this can help you. Have a nice day :-)

Comment: the 4th suggestion helps~ Thanks alot :D